# How does .NET/COM work with multiple versions registered via Regasm?

Tags: com, versions, regasm

I have a .NET DLL (that happens to be written in C++/CLI).  Parts of it I want to expose via COM.  I do this and register it using "regasm my.dll /codebase".  So far so good.  But then I change some things and the version number of the assembly changes plus I move the dll to a different folder.  I register it again and look at my COM object in OLE/COM Viewer.  I see something like this

```
InprocServer32 [Codebase] = file://c://foo/bar/my.dll
7.0.0.0 [Class] = My.Blah.Class
7.0.0.0 [Assembly] = Sync, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1dd19234234
7.0.0.0 [RuntimeVersion] = v2.0.50727
7.0.0.0 [CodeBase] = file://c:/dooby/do/my.dll
7.0.0.27397 [Class] = My.Blah.Class
7.0.0.27397 [Assembly] = Sync, Version=7.0.0.27397, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1dd19234234
7.0.0.27397 [RuntimeVersion] = v2.0.50727
7.0.0.27397 [CodeBase] = file://c://foo/bar/my.dll
```

Questions about multiple versions:

1. So I think that the last COM object that was registered wins.  It doesn't matter if I have my old 7.0.0.0 COM object registered, the 7.0.0.27397 is the one that will be created when I instantiate my COM object because I registered it last.  Is that correct?
2. Oops I didn't keep around the 7.0.0.0 object.  Is there any way to get rid of it?  Is there any way to remove all versions of a COM object other than going into the registry and whacking it by hand?
3. Just out of curiosity, if I specifically wanted to instantiate a particular version of my COM object is there any way to do that? (I'm using C++ if you wanted to give a code example).
4. Is there any way I can just tell regasm to not store the version number because it just seems to be cluttering things up and I can't see what the benefit is.  If my COM object went through significant API change I'd just change the GUID and progid, right?  What if I don't want to register multiple versions (I don't).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always set my COM visible assemblies up with a static AssemblyVersion for just this reason. If you want to have binaries tagged with a version, use AssemblyFileVersion instead.

1. Last registered object wins: yep
2. Not really. You can put stuff in your assembly's ComRegisterFunction/ComUnregisterFunction attributed methods to automate the cleanup, but if you leave old version droppings around, this is about the only way.
3. You'd do it with a different coclass GUID and/or ProgID (eg, MyCoClass.1, .2, etc). CoCreateInstance doesn't know anything about the version values- they're used by the CLR's activator to ensure it loaded the right assembly.
4. No- best thing to do is never change your assembly version (see above).

Comment: I am seeing evidence that COM always picks up the highest-numbered version of a component registered with multiple versions, not the last-registered version. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

Components with the same CLSID should be compatible, especially if you've only changed the build number between assemblies. Here's the only [relevant](http://books.google.com/books?id=hxZLj7oU3WUC&pg=PA262&lpg=PA262&dq=com%2B+components+version+major+minor&source=bl&ots=yPqsrC6Smb&sig=frNJmR07hhQqDmSlvPhIS_ubiAk&hl=en&ei=9kD7SsvMA8rdnAfsmoz7DA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CAgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=com%2B%20components%20version%20major%20minor&f=false) thing I found to confirm this by googling quickly.

To answer your questions directly:

1. Correct.
2. regasm /unregister
3. Look into [Binding redirects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2%28VS.80%29.aspx).
4. Probably not.